# Why is a line in my if statement running every time? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I am working on a project were the user inputs a number and a list, and whatever item in the list is closest to the number, is printed out. I have come across a problem were the line in my if() statement in my while loop is running every time? I have a feeling it has something to do with indenting if() statements in python 3 but I am not certain. Anybody know why this is happening?

```py
import math
MatchingI = math.inf

while i < len(compareList):
    if (abs(int(mainNum) - int(compareList[i])) < MatchingI):
        MatchingI = int(compareList[i])
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to assign `abs(int(mainNum) - int(compareList[i]))` to `MatchingI`, instead of assigning `int(compareList[i])` to `MatchingI`.

```py
import math
MatchingI = math.inf

while i < len(compareList):
    if (abs(int(mainNum) - int(compareList[i])) < MatchingI):
        MatchingI = abs(int(mainNum) - int(compareList[i]))
        answer = compareList[i]
    i += 1

print(answer)
```

Isn't this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Aaron I think you need two variables, one is for the difference and the other is for something like whether it is larger or less.

Comment: It's more probable (by the naming convention) that they want `MatchingI = i` and the comparison to be `< abs(int(mainNum) - int(compareList[MatchingI]))`.

Comment: @Naetmul I didn't see the code part it glitched out and I didn't see the code part, sorry ._.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes with `MatchingI = 0` for initialization